# How to compare 2 values using jstl

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I have lists in controller

```
List l=serviceClientServiceImpl.getSavedParents(clientId); 
uiModel.addAttribute("savedParents",l);
List<Parent> parentList = 
(List<Parent>) serviceClientServiceImpl.getParents("Parent",Long.valueOf(clientId)); 
uiModel.addAttribute("parentList", parentList);
```

and I am retrieving it in jsp like the follow

```
<ul style="max-width: 300px;" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menuId"> 
<c:forEach items="${parentList}" var="test"> 

<li ><a href="#" value="${test.id}-${test.category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" > 
<input type="checkbox" value="${test.id}">${test.name }</a></li> 


</c:forEach> 
</ul> 
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 

<c:forEach items="${savedParents}" var="test1"> 
<ul style="max-width: 300px;" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"> 
<li class="active"><a href="#" value="${test1.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);"> 
<input type="checkbox" value="${test1.id}"></a></li> 

</ul> 
</c:forEach>
```

Now I want to merge the the both and where ever test.id equals to test1.id then I want to add an html `class="active"`

I tried the following way

```
<ul style="max-width: 300px;" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked"  id="menuId">
<c:forEach items="${parentList}" var="test">
<c:forEach items="${savedParents}" var="test1">
<c:when test3="${test.id}==${test1.id }">
  <li ><a href="#" class="active" value="${test.id}-${test.category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" >
  <input type="checkbox" value="${test.id}">${test.name }</a></li>

</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
  <li ><a href="#" value="${test.id}-${test.category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" >
  <input type="checkbox" value="${test.id}">${test.name }</a></li>
</c:otherwise>

</c:forEach>

  <%-- <li ><a href="#" value="${test.id}-${test.category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" >
  <input type="checkbox" value="${test.id}">${test.name }</a></li> --%>


</c:forEach>
 </ul>
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
```

but I am getting error in eclipse

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Missing required attribute 
     "test"
    - Undefined attribute name 
     "test3"
    - Missing required attribute 
     "test"
    - Undefined attribute name 
     "test3"
```

Can any body help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try comparing the strings this way

```
<c:when test="${test.id == test1.id }">
```

you could also use the `eq` instead of `==`

```
<c:when test="${test.id eq test1.id }">
```

Comment: I have another problem.Can you help me?

Comment: Sure if this is related to the same question or different one?

Comment: its not related to this questions.So we can not discuss here. can you come to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44929/java-and-jquery-beginners

Comment: If this problem is solved try to accept answers. People tend not to answer your questions if your not accepting answers, a tip to keep in mind in open forums. cheers!

Comment: Let me see, if I could I will surely.

Comment: Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993097/how-to-use-if-loop-inside-if-loop-using-jstl

Answer (score 2):

It should be `<c:when test=` instead of `<c:when test3=`

try with `c:if` as well

```
<c:set var="id1" value="2" />
<c:set var="id" value="2" />

<c:if test="${id == id1 }">
    Equal
</c:if>
```

OR

```
<c:set var="id1" value="2" />
<c:set var="id" value="2" />

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${id == id1 }">
        Equal
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Not equal
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Read more [JSTL Core conditional Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_choose_tag.htm)

**Note:**

- complete conditional expression must be enclosed inside single `${}`
- `c:when` tag should be enclosed inside the `c:choose` tag

> The `<c:choose>` works like a Java switch statement in that it lets you choose between a number of alternatives. Where the switch statement has case statements, the `<c:choose>` tag has `<c:when>` tags. A a switch statement has default clause to specify a default action and similar way `<c:choose>` has `<c:otherwise>` as default clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Well can you please share some points as why should I change c:when to c:if and why should I use test

Comment: There is no need to switch. I just told you the mistake. Look at the test part if tag as well that is the correct way to test.

Comment: I did your way but it gives me errpr