# how to use if loop inside if loop using jstl

Tags: spring, jstl

I have a requirement where if status is 0 then add a css class active else add a css class active1 and for that I have done like the follow

```
<c:forEach items="${parentList}" var="test">

<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${test[1] eq 0}">
   <li><a href="#" class="active" value="${test[0].id}-${test[0].category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" > 
${test[0].name }</a></li>
  </c:when>

  <c:otherwise>
  <li><a href="#" class="active1" value="${test[0].id}-${test[0].category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" > 
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/ui_resources/img/checked.jpg" alt="" height="20" width="20"/>${test[0].name }</a></li>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

Now my requirement if

`${test[0].category}` is client then add a button `<button name="delete/>`

so now 4 condtions arrise

1. if status is 0 and category is not client then add class active
2. if status is 0 and category is client then add class ="active" and
   add button.
3. if status is not 0 category is client then add class="active1" and
   add button
4. if status is not 0 and category is not client then only add
   class="active".

So can any body please tell me how to use if loop inside if loop using jstl

Comment: I would handle the requirement for class and button seperatly. So basically always class active unless `status is not 0 category is client`. Only add button when category is client. Why would that be 4 conditions? You can determine the class before the `<c:choose ../>` and use the `<c:choose />` to determine to render (or not) the button.

Comment: @M.Deinum So you think I have to create 3 <c:choose>

Comment: No. 1 c:if which set a variable and 1 c:choose. Or create a function you can call to determine the class then you would only need 1 c:choose.

Comment: And you problably want to move the img element to a css class (active1). (Just noticed the image adding for active1).

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you please put as an answer so that I can upvote

Comment: How try with `c:if` tag for `${test[0].category} == 'client'` to determine button add after `</c:choose>` block?

Comment: @suninsky what about id test[0].category is not client

Comment: Just no add button if category is not client?

Comment: @suninsky can you post as an answer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a multitude of `<c:choose />` use `<c:if />` together with a `<c:var />` to determine the class to use. You can also use a `<:if />` for the button, this will require you to move the rendering of the image to the css.

The JSP would look something like this (from the top of my head).

```
<c:forEach items="${parentList}" var="test">
    <c:set var="clazz" value="active" />
    <c:if test="${test[1] ne 0 and test[0].category ne 'client'}">
        <c:set var="clazz" value="active1" />
    </c:if>

    <li>
        <a href="#" class="${clazz}" value="${test[0].id}-${test[0].category}" id="${parent.id}" onclick="return getQuestions(this);" > ${test[0].name }</a>
        <c:if test="${test[0].category eq 'client'}"><button name="delete" /></c:if>
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

You would need something like the following to your css class `active1`

```
a.active1 {
    background-image: url('/resources/ui_resources/img/checked.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 25px;  /* width of the image plus a little extra padding */
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.I will try your way and let you know

Comment: Typed it from the top of my head, probably forgot to close the statemetns somewhere. At the the expression in `<c:if test="..."`  wheren't properly closed. Should have a closing `}`. (Just added).

Comment: It shows error in this line <c:if test="${test[1] ne 0 and test[0].category ne 'client'}"/>
        <c:var name="clazz" value="active1" />
    </c:if>

Comment: Without the error it is hard to tell what is wrong. Also I wouldn't exect it to run as I'm not sure if what you posted is actual code.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Missing start tag for "c:if"
 - No start tag (<c:if>).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54922/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-m-deinum).

Comment: I did that closed the " but still the same

Comment: Did you also add the missing `}`.? But as mentioned the code was a sample to give you the idea I didn't expect it to work (copy-paste style).

Comment: in your code you missed only " I think.You have already closed }

Comment: I have fixed the compiler time error but Now getting runtime error http://pastie.org/9249778

Comment: My bad. Instead of c:var use c:set... (Too much JSF on my mind :S ). and instead of the `name` attribute use `var` .

Comment: There are 2 tags to change.

Comment: the problem now is the image is not getting loaded.

Comment: Fix your location. The image location is relative from the location of the css file and you probably need to fiddle around with the with and some other css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code block, how just add `c:if` tag after `<c:choose>` block?

```
<c:forEach ...>
    <c:choose ...>
    </c:choose>
    <%-- here to check buuton add or not --%>
    <c:if test="${test[0].category == 'client'}"><button name="delete" /></c:if>
</c:forEach
```